# Написать функцию, которая создает объекты разного типа

Tags: c++

Помогите оптимизировать код, одно и тоже действие повторяется 4 раза, разница только в типах объектов, которые добавляются в вектор. Классы Shadow, Speedy, Bashful и Pokey являются производными от одного класса Enemy.

```
    std::vector<Enemy*> SetOfEnemy;

    Object easyEnemyObject = lvl.GetObject("blinky");
    SetOfEnemy.push_back(new Shadow(lvl.GetWidth(), lvl.GetHeight(), easyEnemyObject.rect.left, easyEnemyObject.rect.top, 32, 32));

    Object easyEnemyObject1 = lvl.GetObject("pinky");
    SetOfEnemy.push_back(new Speedy(lvl.GetWidth(), lvl.GetHeight(), easyEnemyObject1.rect.left, easyEnemyObject1.rect.top, 32, 32));

    Object easyEnemyObject2 = lvl.GetObject("inky");
    SetOfEnemy.push_back(new Bashful(lvl.GetWidth(), lvl.GetHeight(), easyEnemyObject2.rect.left, easyEnemyObject2.rect.top, 32, 32));

    Object easyEnemyObject3 = lvl.GetObject("clyde");
    SetOfEnemy.push_back(new Pokey(lvl.GetWidth(), lvl.GetHeight(), easyEnemyObject3.rect.left, easyEnemyObject3.rect.top, 32, 32));
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вам нужно что-то вроде `SetOfEnemy.push_back(createEnemy("blinky"))` но вы не знаете как реализовать `createEnemy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
template<typename T>
T * createEnemy(const char * name)
{
    const auto rect = lvl.GetObject(name).rect;
    return new T(   lvl.GetWidth ()
                  , lvl.GetHeight()
                  , rect.left
                  , rect.top
                  , 32
                  , 32       );
}

//...

std::vector<Enemy*> SetOfEnemy;

SetOfEnemy.push_back(createEnemy<Shadow >("blinky"));
SetOfEnemy.push_back(createEnemy<Speedy >("pinky" ));
SetOfEnemy.push_back(createEnemy<Bashful>("inky"  ));
SetOfEnemy.push_back(createEnemy<Pokey  >("clyde" ));
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ - не мой основной язык, и я не знаю хороших практик и специфики вашего проекта, но почему вам просто не перегрузить конструктор, чтобы у вас получилось что-то типа

```
std::vector<Enemy *> SetOfEnemy = {
  new Shadow(lvl, "blinky"),
  new Speedy(lvl, "pinky"),
  new Bashful(lvl, "inky"),
  new Pokey(lvl, "clyde"),
};
```

`lvl.GetObject`, `lvl.GetWidth`, и `lvl.GetHeight` вызывутся в конструкторе, `32` в аргументах по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0):

Если `"blinky"`, `"pinky"`, `"inky"` и `"clyde"` это просто имена, которые никак не связаны с типом объекта, то можно сделать шаблонную функцию:

```
template<class T>
Enemy* cteateEnemy(const Level& lvl, const std::string &name){
    Object easyEnemyObject = lvl.GetObject(name);
    return new T(lvl.GetWidth(), lvl.GetHeight(), easyEnemyObject .rect.left, easyEnemyObject .rect.top, 32, 32));
}
```